# Font Size (Face Attributes, Height) in Org Mode's Column View

Tags: org-mode, customize-face

Happy New Year!

I use Org Mode and columnview extensively.  The issue I am having is that zooming (`Command +` on MacOs or `C- +` on PC) doesn't work in column view.  Here is an example before zooming in

[image: Column View Before Zooming in]

Now, here is the view after zooming in (using `C- +` on PC and `CMD +` on Mac.

[image: Column View After Zooming in]

You can clearly see text from the property drawer enlarged and the text from the columns unchanged.

I have looked at the face attributes in column view using `C-u C-x =` to get

[image: Face Properties in Column View]

The right-hand buffer with the face information is

[image: Face Information]

I cannot quite figure out where to go from here.  I thought about clicking on the line

[image: Foreground height, family, etc.]

`((:foreground unspecified) (:height 120 :family "Menlo") org-column org-level-2)`

which brings up

[image: org column customize this face]

Clicking on  `(customize this face)` at the top brings up

[image: Customize this face]

Clicking on [image: Show all attributes] brings up this menu

[image: hidden attributes]

Checking `Height` and using `2.0` instead of `1.0` and hitting `Apply` blows up the font of the headers.  I need to increase the font size of the text in the column cells.  Anybody knows how to do this?

[image: Font Size Increase for Headers]

Answer (score 1):

The culprit is Material theme. I like it, but it interferes with font size in Org's column view.